# XML TypedArray only Displaying first image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, typed-arrays

This is my first attempt with TypedArrays and I believe I've written my code correctly, but for some reason I am only able to see the first image in my array. I have a loop that should be displaying the images repeatedly.

My activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_view">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100.0dp"
        android:layout_height="25.0dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:longClickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/soundEnable_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Highscores"
        android:id="@+id/highscores_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Play Game"
        android:id="@+id/startGame_button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="musicIcon">
        <item>@drawable/musicoff</item>
        <item>@drawable/musicon1</item>
        <item>@drawable/musicon2</item>
        <item>@drawable/musicon3</item>
        <item>@drawable/musicon4</item>
        <item>@drawable/musicon5</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

and my activity.java

```
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton musicEnable_ImageButton;
    Handler musicIcon_animate = new Handler();
    int ArrayPos = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


        final TypedArray musicIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.musicIcon);
        for(ArrayPos =0;ArrayPos<5;ArrayPos++) {
            musicIcons.getResourceId(ArrayPos, -1);
        }
        ArrayPos = 0;
        musicEnable_ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.soundEnable_button);
        musicEnable_ImageButton.setImageResource(musicIcons.getResourceId(ArrayPos,-1));
        musicIcons.recycle();
        musicEnable_ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                ArrayPos = 1;
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        musicEnable_ImageButton.setImageResource(musicIcons.getResourceId(ArrayPos,-1));
                        musicIcons.recycle();
                        if(ArrayPos < 5) {
                            ArrayPos++;
                        }
                        else{
                            ArrayPos = 1;
                        }
                        Log.d("test", "timer fired");
                        musicIcon_animate.postDelayed(this, 1);
                    }
                };

                musicIcon_animate.postDelayed(runnable, 1);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only see the first image because you are recycling your `musicIcons` `TypedArray` after you set the first image. `TypedArray.recycle()` removes all of the references to the resources in the array, making it an empty array. You *want* to do this, but only after you've gotten what you need from the array.

In your case, since you are using the resources over a period of time, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
List<Integer> musicIcons = new ArrayList<>();

final TypedArray typedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.musicIcon);

for(int i = 0; i < typedArray.length(); i++) {
    musicIcons.add(typedArray.getResourceId(i, -1);
}

typedArray.recycle();
```

Then set the `ImageView` resource like this:

```
musicEnable_ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(musicIcons.get(ArrayPos));
```

---

But, I also noticed that it looks like you are just trying to animate the icon, in which case, you should look into using an [`AnimationDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). In this way you can just create a drawable XML file:

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicoff" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

Then set the image resource to this `animation-list`, and animate it:

```
musicEnable_ImageButton.setImageResource(R.id.sound_button);

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) musicEnable_ImageButton.getBackground();

frameAnimation.start();
```

On API 21+ it is even easier, you can create an [`AnimatedStateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedStateListDrawable.html) to wrap your `animation-list` (or lists). Then set `android:button` attribute of a `RadioButton` to the `AnimatedStateListDrawable` and watch it animate as you call `setChecked()`.

Comment: is the animation method faster? Right now my delay is delay is really slow.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion You can set the delay to whatever you want, the `android:duration` attribute sets the delay between frames in milliseconds, just like `postDelayed`.

Comment: I was able to see my images, but I wanted to try the animationdrawable method, but my app crashes each time I click the image. I've accepted your answer, as it did fix my problem, but I opened a new question with my updated code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676186/animationdrawable-error-on-button-click/37676400?noredirect=1#comment62842820_37676400

Comment: @1QuickQuestion Ah, I looked at your new question. I think I see the problem, there was a mistake in my code here. I was using `setImageResource()` instead of `setBackgroundResource()`. Otherwise the answer by @BartekLipinski should work.