# AnimationDrawable Error on button click

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-imagebutton

I believe my xml is correct, but I'm not sure what's causing this error in my code. I am trying to attempt animationdrawable on an imagebutton, but each time I click my button I get an error.

Here is my animation-list "music_icon":

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="true">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon1" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon2" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon3" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon4" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon5" android:duration="50" />
    </animation-list>
```

My mainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;


public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton musicEnable_ImageButton;
Handler musicIcon_animate = new Handler();
int ArrayPos = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    musicEnable_ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.soundEnable_button);
    musicEnable_ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.musicoff);
    musicEnable_ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            musicEnable_ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
            final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) musicEnable_ImageButton.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
}
```

my layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_view">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100.0dp"
        android:layout_height="25.0dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:longClickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/soundEnable_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Highscores"
        android:id="@+id/highscores_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Play Game"
        android:id="@+id/startGame_button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the error message:

```
06-07 05:00:48.004 19844-19844/com.example.comp.app_name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
at com.example.comp.app_name.HomeScreen$1.onClick(HomeScreen.java:36)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299219/button-states-with-background-as-animationdrawable-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Change your drawable (remove `selector` tag):

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/musicon5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

2. I can't see you setting the background of the `musicEnable_ImageButton`, you're only trying to `get` it... Am I missing something, or are you just forgetting to set the background in the first place?

Comment: forgive me, I am new to this, but what is the "selector tag"? In regards to setting the background, is "setImageResource" different from setBackgroundResource? Could you provide an example?

Comment: If you compare the drawable that you've posted with the one posted by me, you'll see that the enclosing thing is not `selector` any more, but the `animation-list` itself. `setImageResource` and `setBackgroundResource` are two completely different things. This is an essential part of the `ImageView`.

Comment: removed the selector tag & changed to setImageResource and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "Changed TO setImageResource"?

Comment: My Original:

final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) musicEnable_ImageButton.getBackground();
                musicEnable_ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_icon);

My Change:

final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) musicEnable_ImageButton.getBackground();
                musicEnable_ImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);

I feel like I misunderstood your second suggestion.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion Also, you shouldn't need a `Runnable` or `Handler` at all if you are using an `animation-list`. `frameAnimation.start()` can run on the UI thread.

Comment: First of all, you changed your `setBackgroundResource` incorrectly to `setImageResource`. I didn't tell you to do that, I asked you where were you setting your background. Just this. And now I know why I couldn't see this call. Because the order in which you do stuff doesn't make any sense at all. Why do you try to first `getBackground()` and then you're trying to set the resource on the `ImageView`? It doesn't make any sense. Is the `R.drawable.music_icon` your `animation-list`? If yes, then change the order of your calls. First `setBackgroundResource`, then `getBackground`.

Comment: As for the `handler`, it's useless, `frameAnimation.start()` is enough.

Comment: @BartekLipinski -_- I made all of your changes, still getting the error.

Comment: So what's your current code from the `OnClickListener`

Comment: @Bryan I'm trying to use the button click as a mode change. When the button is clicked I want the animation to start (only after clicking). I removed the runnable but I'm still getting the crash.

Comment: Can you post your current code? Maybe as the edit to your question?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I have updated my question with the code changes; again I am new to java/android-studio so this is all unfamiliar.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion Is it still the `ClassCastException`? That error is telling you that you have a [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) instead of an [`AnimationDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). It does look like your XML up top is correct now, but the only way you can get a `StateListDrawable` is by using the `<selector>` tag.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion Ah, that is a separate issue all together. How big are your music image files? Are you loading other large images onto the screen?

Comment: @Bryan 700x700 .png files

Comment: @1QuickQuestion That is fairly large. If you are positive you want your app to be using such large images, I would suggest setting `android:largeHeap="true"` on your application in your manifest, but this basically relegates your app as a resource hog. Otherwise, maybe consider using smaller icons?

Comment: @1QuickQuestion your button (`soundEnable_button`) is `50dp`x`50dp`, you most certainly don't need 700x700 png files for your animation frames

Comment: @1QuickQuestion `50dp` for `xxxhdpi` devices (huuuuge ones) is `200px`

Comment: @BartekLipinski thank you (I decreased the size of the images)!